# Bash sorting by 3rd column and 1st column

Tags: bash, sorting, awk

Intake file

```
website1 ip 20
website1 ip 30
website1 ip 10
website2 ip 200
website2 ip 10 
website3 ip 150
```

I need it to sort so that the sum of  the 3rd with the associated website  will show first with the highest total with the website

website2 has 210 website 3 has 150 website1 has 60

```
website2 ip 200
website2 ip 10
website3 ip 150
website1 ip 30
website1 ip 20
website1 ip 10
```

ive tried sort -k3n -k1n but that is not the results i am looking for 230     website2 ip 200

Comment: You probably won't find a "pure" `sort` solution.  `sort` compares on a line-by-line basis but your sorting criteria depends on sorting in groups, then lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk to have 2 pass and sum the column 3 per website (column 1) and append a new column in the output. Then sort using new column in output and finally strip first column from output using `cut`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sum[$1]+=$3; next} {print sum[$1] "\t" $0}' file file |
sort -k1nr -k4nr |  cut -f2-

website2 ip 200
website2 ip 10
website3 ip 150
website1 ip 30
website1 ip 20
website1 ip 10
```

**Output** of `awk` command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{sum[$1]+=$3; next} {print sum[$1] "\t" $0}' file file

60  website1 ip 20
60  website1 ip 30
60  website1 ip 10
210 website2 ip 200
210 website2 ip 10
150 website3 ip 150
```

Comment: Hey @anubhava thanks for the help! , it is sorting by the sum of hte first column but it is not putting the 4th column in order

Comment: You can also try this command: `awk 'FNR==NR{sum[$1]+=$3; next} {print sum[$1] "\t" $0}' file file | sort -k1nr -k4nr | cut -f2-`

Comment: ahhhh I know what the problem is. my raw text file isn't as perfect as my example. there is 2 spaces between the IP and the count so it doesnt work. I just need to clean it up and it works !

Comment: Actually thats not the problem so why is it it will sort website1,website2,website3 but not real websites.....

Comment: If you can provide me a sample of your actual data on pastebin.com then I can surely look into that.

Comment: posted on pastebin.com

Comment: You need to provide me a link of your pastebin.com and don't forget to also post your expected output.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/PZBGG3hK youll see that the 4th colum is not sorting, your assumption initially is what i am looking for

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128853/discussion-between-anubhava-and-brianpb245).

Comment: Join the chat by clicking above link to resolve your problem.